# Initializing Camera and uploading file in Android through a website

Tags: android

I have a asp.net website on a public server and it has a form. The button on the form should initialize a camera and when capture is done, the image file should be uploaded on the server to save it in the database.

We implemented this for Iphone though a webapp called QuickPic. We call this application through the javascript. The link below has the javascript code for the same.
http://www.resolved-technologies.com/php/cliqcliq-quickpic-upload-for-php/

We are looking for the similar thing for Android. For now whatever forum I visited in relation, they all point to developing a java based web app e.g. PhoneGap which is not an option for us.

So I have two questions: 
Is there any native AndroidAPI which can be called via Javascript and enable to interact with the Camera and upload an image?
or 
Is there any Android APP which can be called via Javascript for intitializing camera and upload an image?

Thanks,

Vijay

Answer (score 2):

Here is some native Java code that may help you:

Use this to initialize the camera:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), CameraView.class);
startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
```

Here is CameraView:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraView extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraView";

private SurfaceView preview=null;
private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
private Camera camera=null;
private boolean inPreview=false;
private ImageView takePicture;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.cameraview);

takePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.take_picture);

preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
previewHolder
    .setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

preview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        takePicture.setEnabled(false);
        camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);

    }

});


takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
        inPreview=false;    
    }

});


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
try{
    if (camera==null) {
      camera=Camera.open();
      camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
      Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters(); 
      params.set("rotation", 90); 
      camera.setParameters(params);

    }
}catch (Exception e){
    finish();
}
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
if (inPreview) {
  camera.stopPreview();
}
if(camera != null)
    camera.release();
camera=null;
inPreview=false;

super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.options, menu);

return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId()==R.id.camera) {
  if (inPreview) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
    inPreview=false;
  }
}

return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width,
  int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
Camera.Size result=null;

for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
  if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
    if (result==null) {
      result=size;
    }
    else {
      int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
      int newArea=size.width*size.height;

      if (newArea>resultArea) {
        result=size;
      }
    }
  }
}

return(result);
}

SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
  }
  catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("PictureDemo-surfaceCallback",
        "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
    Toast.makeText(CameraView.this, t.getMessage(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
    int format, int width, int height) {
  Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();

    parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();

    inPreview=true;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // no-op
}
};

Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback() {
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

      Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
      Constants.currImageURI = uriTarget;
      OutputStream imageFileOS;

      try {

       imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
       imageFileOS.write(data);
       imageFileOS.flush();
       imageFileOS.close();

       Toast.makeText(CameraView.this, "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();

      }
      setResult(RESULT_OK);
      finish();

}
};
    AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback(){

       @Override
       public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        takePicture.setEnabled(true);
       }};

}
```

and this will help you get the image to the server:

```
    public String uploadUserPhoto(File image) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    Bitmap resized;


    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);

    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "mobileimage.jpg");


    DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient;
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://com.yourserver");

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  

        multipartEntity.addPart("userfile", bab);

        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

        HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.d(TAG, "response: " + responseBody);
        return responseBody;

    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```